# Can someone explain what I am doing wrong in applying Css to custom Button element

Tags: css, reactjs

I am learning react.
I am creating a custom button element and my Css is not being applied to the button element. What am I doing wrong?

**Header.JS**

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "../UI/Button"
import classes from "./Header.css"
const Header = () => {
const loginHandler = () => {};
return <React.Fragment>
    <div className="headerdiv">
        <Button className="headerButton" clickHandler={loginHandler} label=  

{"Login/Logout"}></Button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    };
    export default Header;
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Button = (prop) => {
    return (


        <button onClick={prop.clickHandler}>{prop.label}</button>
        );
    };

export default Button;
```

**Header.css**

```
 .headerButton {
  background-color: rgb(179, 44, 44);
  color: rgb(238, 64, 64);

}
.headerdiv {
  background-color: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import is wrong and you are applying the classname to the component "Button" not the "button"

Change

```
//remove import from Header.js
import classes from "./Header.css"
//also remove classname
<Button clickHandler={loginHandler} label=  

{"Login/Logout"}></Button>


//Add to button.js
import "./Header.css"
//Add the className to your button
<button className="headerButton" onClick={prop.clickHandler}>{prop.label}</button>
```

Should work now :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it. Button background color is still white.

Comment: @AyushChittranshi sorry just seen where you went wrong. Updating answer now

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and being patient.

Comment: @AyushChittranshi No problem! Please mark answer as answered with the tick if you are happy its resolved now :)

Comment: As you can see I am an amateur. It worked. Thanks a lot. So if I am correct Css styles cannot be applied directly to custom element?

Comment: @AyushChittranshi We all start somewhere. Yes and no so if you wanted to use that same "Button" component but with different styles you could add a prop of className and define it that way. Happy to post an example if you dont understand what i am on about